# Can I create a file and write values to it by placing the code NODE.js in JS file which going to call it from HTML?

Tags: node.js

Here's a simple code that works when run from the VSC terminal.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'json'), err => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('File created');
});

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'json', 'temp.txt');

fs.writeFile(filePath, 'Some value', err => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('Value was signed into the file');

});
```

Now, I put the same thing into the JS file, which has some calculations and I want to write the result to the file. This does not work.

```
            project_data = [];
            project_data[0] = parseInt(initial_data);
            for (i=1;  i < len_table; i++) {
                project_data[i] = parseInt(project_data[i-1]) + 1;
            }
            
            const oil_production_map = new Map();
            for (i = 0; i < len_table; i++) {
                oil_production_map.set(project_data[i],parseInt(oil_production[i])); 
            }
        

            const fs = require('fs');
            const path = require('path');
            
            fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'json'), err => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                alert('File created');
            });
            
            const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'json', 'oil_production_file.txt');
            
            fs.writeFile(filePath, 'Some value', err => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
            
                alert('Value was signed into the file');
            
            });
```

[Require in not defined.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiXKv.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this thread : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762282/using-node-jss-file-system-functions-from-a-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762282/using-node-jss-file-system-functions-from-a-browser)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It seems to me that this method is not entirely suitable for me, since I need to create a server and contact it through the API. Perhaps this is a solution, but not for my current level of knowledge. I will try to find another ways to save data, for use them on other pages of HTML and files of JS.