# In Node.js app, calling the 'fs' module from a html file living in a subfolder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js app that looks like this:

```
/public
/views
   bbtFaceSimilarity.html
package.json
server.js
```

In *package.json*:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

In *server.js*:

```
const app = express()
fs = require('fs')
...
app.get('/bbt_face_similarity', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(viewsDir, 'bbtFaceSimilarity.html')))
```

In *bbtFaceSimilarity.html*:

```
<script>
async function UploadImage() {
      const imgFile = document.getElementById('upload_image').files[0]
      const img = await faceapi.bufferToImage(imgFile)
      fs.writeFile('downloaded.jpg', img, 'binary');
}
</script>
```

As you can see I am trying to call the *fs* module from an html file.

I don't understand why, the *fs* variable being created without the keyword `const` or `let`, it is not callable from the html file. Indeed I get the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: fs is not defined

Any idea where this is coming from ?

Thanks

Comment: `fs` is a Node.js module. It cannot be used in the browser.

Comment: You’re trying to call fs from the browser? And it’s not being created, that’s why it’s undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using node.js's File System functions from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762282/using-node-jss-file-system-functions-from-a-browser)

Comment: The html javascript executes on your browser, meanwhile your `server.js` code executes on your server. The browser doesn't have an `fs` module, so it won't work if you try to use it in the html.

Comment: Indeed, but I need to save the image on the client's side